# Javascript won't work: Encoding error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

Whenever I try this, I get the following error in the Firefox console:

[09:20:30.028] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<title>this is a title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script>
function showAnswer(){
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML="This is the answer";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="q">
This is a question?
<button action="showAnswer()">Show Answer</button>
</div>
<div id="ans">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: maybe because you're declaring the encoding twice?

Comment: There's no "action" attribute on `<button>` tags.  You (probably) want "onclick".

Comment: after taking out one of them, it still doesn't work

Comment: replaced 'action' with 'onclick' and it still doesn't work

Comment: The encoding message is a warning, not an error, so its unlikely to be related to your JS issue.

Comment: @ScorpionByte, replacing `action` by `onclick` *is* the solution. If it did not work, set up a jsfiddle to show exactly what you tried and identify the browser(s) on which “it still doesn’t work” (clicking on the button has no effect, I presume).

Answer (score 3):

You only need;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: see Alex's answer for the 'onclick'. Should get it working for you

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of

```
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

You just want...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This is also wrong...

```
<button action="showAnswer()">Show Answer</button>
```

Probably want...

```
<button type="button" onclick="showAnswer()">Show Answer</button>
```

> **See http://jsfiddle.net/5Qtq2/**